# Apex REST API - Unable to set StatusCode to 429

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, rest-service

I am trying to set the status code to 429 for Too many request using the code below:

```
if(Limits.getQueries() < Limits.getLimitQueries()){
              upsert UpdateData;
              }
              else if((Limits.getQueries() >= Limits.getLimitQueries()))
              {
                  RestContext.response.statusCode = 429;
                  UpdateError[] err = new UpdateError[]{ 
                  new UpdateReturnError(UpdateData.Id, 'Too many Requests', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId)
                };
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
              }
            }
```

I am getting the following error in the raw response:

[image]

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 7):

`429 Too Many Requests` is not an appropriate status to return from Apex that is processing a REST request, and so presumably that's why the server prevents you from doing so. The [relevent RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4) indicates that this response is for rate-limiting, ie, the number of HTTP requests received from a single client in a given amount of time:

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
> requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the
> condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long
> to wait before making a new request.

Each REST request will be a separate Apex transaction, and the # of SOQL queries issued is a per-transaction limit. So exceeding that limit would never be because too many calls to your endpoint had come from a single client in a given period of time.

The [documentation for the `RestResponse` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm?search_text=HTTP%20Response) lists the acceptable values for the `statusCode` property, and `429` is not included.

This should probably be a `200` response, or perhaps a `500`. You're successfully receiving and processing the HTTP request. It's just that the result of that request exceeded a limit, but that limit is at a layer much further down than the HTTP server.